# Alignment and Colors of Data Point Outliers of Box Plot

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Is it possible to align the data points and outliers of box plot in one straight line like in center of box plot?

Additionally, can I color the data points?

The current and the desired screen shot are attached with it.

[image: Current]

[image: Current]

[image: Desired functionality]

Comment: Did you try [.dataWidthPortion(0)](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BoxPlot.html#dataWidthPortion)?

Comment: It worked. i used dataWidthPortion(0.1) my bad. Moreover is it possible to color the data points like in desired pic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.dataWidthPortion(0)
```

to not spread the points out at all. [Documentation](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BoxPlot.html#dataWidthPortion).

General advice on changing the color or style of anything, if there is no accessor for it:

1. Look for the chart in the [chart selectors wiki](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/Chart-selectors), or if it's not there, inspect the item you want to change in the developer tools and find out what SVG tag and CSS class the item has. In this case, it's `circle.data`
2. Add a `pretransition` handler which selects the items you want, and changes them:

   ```
   var cc = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeDark2);
   bp02.on('pretransition', chart => {
       chart.selectAll('circle.data').attr('fill', function(d) {
           const boxDatum = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
           return cc(boxDatum.value[d]);
       })
   });
   ```

   In this case, we're creating an ordinal scale to map the available data to the colors in [a color scheme](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/v1.5.0/README.md#schemeDark2).

The interesting question is here is what data to bind to the color of the dots, and how to get that data.

A box plot's data consists of an array of key/value pairs where each value is a Y value. When the box plot draws it will bind each `circle.dot` element to the *index of the data in the array*.

So we need to get the array that is bound to the box. Luckily `d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()` will give us the key/value pair for the box.

For this example, we are encoding the color based on the Y value, which we get by looking inside `boxDatum.value`. You don't specify how you want the dots colored but this shows the data that is available.

[image: colored dots]