# How can I retrieve the original data row to a dc.js boxplot data-point?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Im using dc.js to create a Boxplot which is working as expected. To add some more interactivity to the chart I wanted to enable the user to click on outliers to retrieve additional information.

Therefore I created an event handler as it is explained in the [D3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#handling-events). The result is working as expected and I get the event fired when a user clicks on the data-point. My expectation was that somehow I will then be able to access the original data to retrieve the sfc attribute to the clicked data-point but I failed and do currently not have any idea how to resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const data = [{
    "duration": 248,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809783",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 249,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809676",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 156,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809676",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 254,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BP0L2809798",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 134,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809783",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 128,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BP0L2809798",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 228,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248B90L2809800",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 125,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248B90L2809800",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 242,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809792",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 149,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809792",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 237,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809819",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 153,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809819",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 232,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809847",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 482,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809847",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 238,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809883",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 143,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809883",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 213,
    "type": "M247",
    "sfc": "M247B50L2693004",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 217,
    "type": "M247",
    "sfc": "M247B50L2693004",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 229,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BC0L2809902",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 151,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BC0L2809902",
    "pass": 0
  }
];

const cycletimeChart = dc.boxPlot('#cycletime-chart');

const ndx = crossfilter(data),
  typeDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.type;
  }),
  cycletimeGroupByType = typeDimension.group().reduce(function(p, v) {
    // keep array sorted for efficiency
    p.splice(d3.bisectLeft(p, v.duration), 0, v.duration);
    return p;
  }, function(p, v) {
    p.splice(d3.bisectLeft(p, v.duration), 1);
    return p;
  }, function() {
    return [];
  });

cycletimeChart
  .dimension(typeDimension)
  .group(cycletimeGroupByType)
  .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('circle.outlier').on('click.sfcClick', function(datum, index, nodes) {
      console.log(`Clicked on outlier with array index ${datum}, ${index}, ${nodes}.`);
      //Here I would like to retrieve the the sfc attribute from the original data object.
    });
  });
cycletimeChart.render();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Boxplot test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/dc@4/dist/dc.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/dc@4/dist/style/dc.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cycletime-chart"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems here:

1. Since crossfilter aggregates the data, only what you provide in the reduce function will be available.
2. The boxplot binds the array index to the outliers, rather than the data.
3. You'll run into trouble with filtering if those durations are not unique.

### 1. Passing the entire row through crossfilter

Since crossfilter is all about aggregation, the original data is not available by default. One workaround is to change the reduction to store `v` instead of `v.duration`:

```
  bisectLeft = d3.bisector(d => d.duration).left,
  cycletimeGroupByType = typeDimension.group().reduce(function(p, v) {
    // keep array sorted for efficiency
    p.splice(bisectLeft(p, v.duration), 0, v);
    return p;
  }, function(p, v) {
    p.splice(bisectLeft(p, v.duration), 1);
    return p;
  }, function() {
    return [];
  });
```

Since `dc.boxPlot` expects an array of numbers, you'll also need to change the `valueAccessor` to extract the durations:

```
  .valueAccessor(d => d.value.map(r => r.duration))
```

### 2. Getting the datum using the array index

As described in [Alignment and Colors of Data Point Outliers of Box Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374263/alignment-and-colors-of-data-point-outliers-of-box-plot/60377456#60377456), the dc.js boxplot binds the *array index* to the outlier dots.

Since the crossfilter key/value pair is bound to the parent `<g>` element, the original datum can be retrieved with the incantation

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().value[datum]
```

### 3. Non-unique durations

In step one we started saving the rows of data in the reduction, instead of just the durations. There is a problem if these durations are not unique: the wrong value might get removed from the array when the row is filtered out.

To be more careful, we should scan for the exact value instead of removing the first entry with the same duration:

```
  function(p, v) {
    let i = d3.bisectLeft(p, v.duration);
    while(p[i] !== v) ++i;
    p.splice(i, 1);
    return p;
  }
```

Caveat: this is untested, since there is no filtering in your example.

```js
const data = [{
    "duration": 248,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809783",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 249,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809676",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 156,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809676",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 254,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BP0L2809798",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 134,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809783",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 128,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BP0L2809798",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 228,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248B90L2809800",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 125,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248B90L2809800",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 242,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809792",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 149,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809792",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 237,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809819",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 153,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BJ0L2809819",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 232,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809847",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 482,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809847",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 238,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809883",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 143,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BK0L2809883",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 213,
    "type": "M247",
    "sfc": "M247B50L2693004",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 217,
    "type": "M247",
    "sfc": "M247B50L2693004",
    "pass": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 229,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BC0L2809902",
    "pass": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 151,
    "type": "M248",
    "sfc": "M248BC0L2809902",
    "pass": 0
  }
];

const cycletimeChart = dc.boxPlot('#cycletime-chart');

const ndx = crossfilter(data),
  typeDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.type;
  }),
  bisectLeft = d3.bisector(d => d.duration).left,
  cycletimeGroupByType = typeDimension.group().reduce(function(p, v) {
    // keep array sorted for efficiency
    p.splice(bisectLeft(p, v.duration), 0, v);
    return p;
  }, function(p, v) {
    let i = bisectLeft(p, v.duration);
    while(p[i] !== v) ++i;
    p.splice(i, 1);
    return p;
  }, function() {
    return [];
  });

cycletimeChart
  .dimension(typeDimension)
  .group(cycletimeGroupByType)
  .valueAccessor(d => d.value.map(r => r.duration))
  .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('circle.outlier').on('click.sfcClick', function(datum, index, nodes) {
      console.log(`Clicked on outlier with datum, index, nodes ${datum}, ${index}, ${nodes}.`);
      console.log('parent array', d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().value);
      console.log(`Original datum`, d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().value[datum]);
      //Here I would like to retrieve the the sfc attribute from the original data object.
    });
  });
cycletimeChart.render();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Boxplot test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/dc@4/dist/dc.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/dc@4/dist/style/dc.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cycletime-chart"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and comprehensive answer. I've implemented suggestions 1) and 2). 3) is not an issue here in the example since all `duration` values are unique. Unfortunately I still cannot get the correct value since `datum` doesn't contain the correct index in the `datum()` array. In the example above `datum` is 17, but the correct object has the index position 4 in the `datum()` array. It's the same in your code snippet above. The correct duration would be 482 but 248 is returned.

Comment: What I wrote was correct but I got bisection wrong; it was comparing numbers against objects and sorting the arrays incorrectly. This did not break the chart because [the box plot sorts the data internally](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1527). So the index did not match the array. Fixed above.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help, your answer solved my problem perfectly. I was wondering if I should add this method to one of the examples in [the examples section](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/). What would you suggest?

Comment: That would be great! Ideally the example would show something when a dot is clicked, like showing the details in another div or d3-tip popup. Also, I think the dots could be made easier to click by giving them a transparent fill rather than `none` (haven’t tried this though).